# Sorting array objects from JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, cordova, sorting

I am trying to develop an app with jQuery mobile. I have a JSON file:

```
[{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com"
},{
  "title": "title you desire",
  "url" : "thisistheurl.com"
}]
```

I am now retrieving the data from the file into an array of objects in JS:

```
var linkList = [];
        $.getJSON('linklist.json').success(function (json) {
        $.each(json, function(i, obj) {
            linkList.push(obj);
        });
        }).then(function() {



      linkList.sort(function(a, b){
      var nameA=a.title.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.title.toLowerCase();
      if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
       return -1;
     if (nameA > nameB)
       return 1;
         return 0; //default return value (no sorting)
     });

$.each( linkList, function( key, val ) {


        var $li;
        $li = $("<li><a href='#' data-status='Downloaded'>"+val.title+"</a></li>");

        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileSource + val.title + ".pdf", success, fail);

        function success() {
            $li.find("a").on("click", function(){ openPdf(val.title); });
            $li.find("a").data('status', 'Downloaded');
            $("#linkList").append($li).listview('refresh');

        }

        function fail() {
            $li.find("a").on("click", function(){ downloadPdf(val.title,val.url); });
            $li.find("a").data('status', 'Not downloaded');
            $("#linkList").append($li).listview('refresh');
        }


    });
    $("#linkList")
                .listview({
                autodividers: true,
                autodividersSelector: function (li) {
                var out = li.find('a').data("status");
                return out;
            }
    }).listview('refresh');





});

    }
```

I am using Phonegap and testing on my phone, so it's not that many ways to debug, but something is wrong with my sorting. Everything works fine if I don't have the sorting (except that data isn't sorted of course), but I would like to have a way to sort them by title.

Comment: So, it's because .getJSON is asynchronous? If so, how can I sort this?

Comment: I am doing so, ain't I?

Comment: obviously, you have callback provided. just drop the rest of the code in there and it will work

Comment: A good way to debug this is to serve your html files locally and use chrome dev tools/console to inspect the JavaScript objects.

Comment: I have added the rest of the code. As I said, if I remove the sort, it works (but without the sorting).

Comment: @hagope Somehow it is not working locally. Might have something to do with it checking for local files.

Comment: are you trying to open the html file in chrome, or are you serving the entire folder (you can use simple web server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are trying to access data before it is loaded. You can put `.then` block right after `getJson` and put all code there including sorting.
Then block will be called when getJson promise will be resolved.

Links:
[Deffered.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)

Comment: In first line of sorting function you have forgot ';' in end of line.